# Http Handler/Azure SQL concurrency issue

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure, iis, dapper

I have the following situation, one web app, running under **IIS** on **Azure App Service**. Said app, connect to a database on **Azure Sql** to update records on a table. My problem is that two calls made really, really close seems to be calling INSERT on the table two times with the same key, and both succeeding.

Now, the details are:

SQL schema: **Notification**

`Id     => uniqueidentifier (unique key)
Status => int`

My web app is regular `IHttpHandler` and the code is below.

```
    <!-- language: c# -->
    public class NotificationStatus : IHttpHandler
    {
        internal class Notification
        {
            public Guid Id { get; set; }
            public int Status { get; set; }

            SqlConnection Connection; /* Not mapped for obvious reasons */
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            Guid id = GetFromContext(context, "id");
            int status = GetFromContext(context, "status");

            Notification not = Db.RetrieveRow(id); /* Create connection from pool */

            try
            {
                if (not == null)
                {
                    not = new DbRecord
                    {
                        Id = id,
                        Status = status,
                    };

                    Db.InsertRow(not); /* Create connection from pool */
                }
                else
                {
                    if (status > not.Status) /* Prevent setting a minor status */
                    {
                        not.Status = status
                        Db.UpdateRecord(not); /* Use connection attached to the object */
                    }
                }

                context.Response.Write("ok");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                context.Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

The `Db` is a simple wrapper around `Dapper` library.

So, the request were:

1. `http://myapp.net/notificationstatus.ashx?id=a58441ae-28ac-48f5-ba5a-730060863f17&status=3`
2. `http://myapp.net/notificationstatus.ashx?id=a58441ae-28ac-48f5-ba5a-730060863f17&status=1`

In the end, the record on the db show `Status = 1`, and both request returned *ok*, Which shouldn't happen.
At this point, I have no idea on what's going on, as far as I know, **IIS** runs every request on thread, there's nothing shared there. `SqlConnections` are retrieved from a pool, so I doubt there's sharing there.

Does anyone knows what might be happening here.

Answer (score 0):

> In the end, the record on the db show Status = 1, and both request returned ok, Which shouldn't happen.

Firstly, according to your code, we could find that if the code do not cause exception while processing request in ProcessRequest method, this code `context.Response.Write("ok");` will always be executed, so the response is **ok**.

Secondly, you could remote debug the code to trace Notification object not and variable status to check what really is happing while processing two requests, and make sure if the condition `status > not.Status` could meet and it does a update operation.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand your answer.

Comment: Do you try to [remote debug](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/#remotedebug) the code to trace the changes of **Status** and what really is happing in ``public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)`` method?

Comment: That won't work. It only happens once in a while. It's very hard to debug because those are two different threads, that will need to collide while debugging.